# Need help installing Whatsapp on a new phone

Tags: backup, sync, whatsapp-messenger, restore, google-drive

I recently upgraded my phone to a newer model. My old phone was rooted (using Kingroot) and I had somehow installed a program that allowed me to force moving an app to the SD card, which is what I did with Whatsapp since it used up the available space extremely quickly.

On my new phone (which I installed the same SD card, but wiped it), when I try to open up Whatsapp, I get:

[image]

Unfortunately my device doesn't even have 2.6 GB total free space after all the system apps eat up most of the storage, however the SD card is empty and has plenty of space.

In my Whatsapp backup on Google Drive I have lots of things I don't even want backed up. Is there a way to manually edit the backup in Google Drive and remove some of the large files to reduce the size and be able to back it up with the space I have on my device?

If not, if I root my device again (which I would really prefer not to do) and move Whatsapp to the SD card again, would that fix the problem, or is it still going to keep looking in the internal storage to restore the backup?

Or let me know if you have an easier solution. I simply don't want to lose some of the photos and videos there as well as chat history.

Note: I tried doing https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout, however the archive created when I select Google Drive is only about 150 MB - nowhere near what my Whatsapp backup is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I don't want my Whatsapp Media to restore (Google Drive BackUp)!](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/133066/i-dont-want-my-whatsapp-media-to-restore-google-drive-backup)

Comment: @xavier_fakerat That doesn't answer my question. That's only about deleting the entire backup. My question states that I want to only delete *some*, but not *all* files from the backup so that it will fit on my phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to download your whatsapp application data from Google Drive, [here's a tool for that](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/tool-whatsapp-google-drive-extractor-t3483633). You can then delete any media you wish and restore your messages and the remaining media back into WhatsApp.